# MessageBox when closing form

Tags: c#, exit, messagebox

Upon closing the form by clicking on the button I created named 'Exit' I want it to display a messagebox asking the user "Are you sure you want to exit?" I don't know the syntax for it, can someone help me please? Thanks

Comment: Can you show the entire function?  Where are you putting this code, is there an `if` statement around that expression, etc?

Comment: private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){}

Comment: Here is fragment from msdn documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/system.windows.forms.messagebox.aspx. Look at examples section.

Comment: Im putting it into that, and nope their is no if statement

Comment: May I suggest an alternative: Why don't you forget about this question and simply trust your users a little more? Perhaps, when they press an exit/close button, that might actually be exactly what they want... no need in asking a second time.

Comment: @stakx Dude, that really isnt the point! Its' all about learning

Comment: @rvngkaz: I can appreciate that, and I apologize if my comment comes across as a mere, "Why would you want to do *that*!?". But why limit your learning to churning out code even when an alternative non-code solution (a UI/UX design decision in this case) might be better?

Comment: @stakx I suppose you've got a point but hey! I just want to go through the basics:P Also, a red lines coming underneath the 'e.cancel' when I've put as the arg 'FormClosedEventArgs' why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure?", "Exit Application?", 
    MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.No)
{
    // ignore it
}
else
{
    // shutdown code goes here
}
```

There's an [MSDN example here.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.dialogresult.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You need to look at the Form. closing event. You can place your message box there and then if you want to abort the form closing set e.cancel = true.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like:

```
private void exitToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if(MessageBox.Show("Exit Application?", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
   {
      this.Close();
   }
}
```